# Image data rotating 45 degrees after resizing

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a snippet of code that utilizes the `ImageIO` library to resize an image to make it smaller when uploading to Parse. Upon uploading, the picture becomes rotated 45 degrees counterclockwise.

```
let imageBytes = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0)
let size = CGSizeMake(1024, 1024)
if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageBytes, nil) {

  let options: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
    kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: NSNumber(double: Double(max(size.width, size.height)) / 2.0),
    kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent: true,
    kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: false
  ]

  //2. Recreate the Image that has been scaled
  let scaledImage = UIImage(CGImage: CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options))
  let scaledImageBytes = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(scaledImage, 1.0)

  let metaData = [
    "imageBytes": scaledImageBytes, //for some reason, scaledImageBytes causes a 90 degree rotation on the picture. Using unscaled image for now.
  ]
  //3. upload the image to Parse
  PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("uploadImage", withParameters: metaData) { message, error in
    if let error = error {
      println("error uploading: \(error)")
    } else if let message = message as? String {
      println("success: \(message)")
    }
  }
}
```

How can I resolve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this function to normalize your image

```
func normalizeImage(raw: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    if raw.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Up {
        return raw
    }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(raw.size, false, raw.scale)
    raw.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: raw.size))
    var normalizedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return normalizedImage
}
```